# SAML enabled site

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

We want to implement single sign on in our applications and want to use OKTA api.

But our application need to be SAML enabled for us to proceed forward.

Currently we use forms authentication in our applications.

Could someone share details about how can we implement SAML in our application.

Any sample code or links are appreciated.

Comment: Please share more details. What's your server-side language?

Comment: We have both asp. Net application on. Net framework 4 and some. Net core applications.  All are mvc and c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you need a client side SAML stack.

Refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)  for a list of stacks available.

I strongly suggest you use one of these rather than roll your own.